# How to register service with the same instance in Prism with Unity?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, prism

I've a Prism Module (implementing `IModule`).

In the `RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)`, I need to say that ONE instance of the class `A` is the one to return when requesting the interfaces  `IA` and `IAprime`:

```
public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IA, A>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IAprime, A>();
}
```

But if I do this, I end by having two different singleton. How should I proceed?

I cannot use the `RegisterInstance` because it would require me to build A, which has some dependency.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: use `RegisterInstance`?

Comment: @vasily.sib and how do you create this instance? Like I said, it has some dependencies to be injected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<A>();
    containerRegistry.Register<IA, A>();
    containerRegistry.Register<IAprime, A>();
}
```

Sure if you need one instance of A, and A must be registered as IA, IAprime.